# Always be logged in to gmail in puppeteer's chromium

Tags: recaptcha, captcha, chromium, puppeteer, google-chrome-headless

I want to reduce risk of having google recaptcha to solve, so I want to be always logged in on gmail, just like on normal chrome. I dont want to manually login every browser start. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use 'userDataDir' option ,while launching puppeteer. 'userDataDir' is a path to browser's user data directory. Find user directory by using "chrome://version" URL. UserDataDir is parent of Profile path.
refer [https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#puppeteerlaunchoptions][2](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#puppeteerlaunchoptions)

Comment: this is a good method, but what if I want to open multiple instances?  this would give an error.